# Evento Javascript Onchange não funciona no navegador de SmartPhone

Tags: php, javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

Criei uma chamada em um checkbox para uma função de JS e no desktop está funcionando perfeitamente, já no navegador do smartphone simplesmente não funciona. Tenho outras funções que são chamadas da mesma forma em inputs de format text na mesma tela e não tenho problemas. Já essa chamada no checkbox para smartphone deu pau. Alguém já passou por um problemas semalhante?

Essa é a div onde chamo a função:

```
<div ><!--class="checkbox">-->
<label><input type="checkbox" id="itemCheck" name="itemCheck" class="flat" onchange="verificafleg()"> Unable to calibrate</label>
</div>
```

e essa é a função no arquivo JS:

```
function verificafleg(){
    controle = window.document.getElementById("comment").value;
    if (controle == ""){
        document.getElementById('comment').value = "Unable to calibrate.";
        document.getElementById('comment').setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    } else if (controle = "Unable to calibrate.") {
        document.getElementById('comment').value = "";
        document.getElementById('comment').removeAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    }
    
    
}
```

Se alguém tiver uma luz aí tô aceitando rs....

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. Você já marcou uma resposta como aceita (quando clicou no ✓) e isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente descobri o que era. Precisava habilitar o certificado SSL do site onde eu estava hospedando. Mesmo com o javascript do navegador ativado o site não possuindo o SSL o navegador não interpretava corretamente o javascript do campo mencionado acima. Foi só habilitar o SSL e problema resolvido.